# Parameter estimation using copulas

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, copula

I am struggling with a pretty basic question in parameter estimation using MLE of Copula ( and its underlying distribution)

I have data X, which is independently sampled from a mixture of two bivariate Gaussian distributions. I want to estimate the mixing proportions of these two bivariate distributions, $\pi$ & $1 - \pi $, their corresponding means $\mu_1$ & $\mu_2$, their var-covar matrices $\Sigma_1$ & $\Sigma_2$.

**In the Gaussian Space, the likelihood is given by:**
\begin{align}
L & = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left( \pi \left( \log \left(  \Phi \left( X_i ; \mu_1, \Sigma_1 \right)\right) \right) + (1- \pi) \left( \log \left(  \Phi \left(X_i ; \mu_2, \Sigma_2 \right)\right) \right) \right)
\end{align}

I can maximize the above likelihood and get the estimates the parameters.

However, what happens if we try to maximize the likelihood in the copula space and get the parameter estimates?

**In the Copula Space, the likelihood is given by:**

\begin{align}
L & = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \log \left( \frac{ \pi \ \Phi \left( X_i; \mu_1, \Sigma_1 \right) + (1-\pi)\Phi \left( X_i; \mu_2, \Sigma_2 \right)  } {\prod_{j=1}^{2} ( 
\pi \Phi_{j}(X_{ij}; \mu_{1j} \Sigma_{1jj}) + (1-\pi) \Phi_{j}(X_{ij}; \mu_{2j} \Sigma_{1jj}) )  } \right)
\end{align}

Here $\Phi_j$ are the marginals along each direction.

I know, usually, it is easier and more straight forward to maximize in Gaussian likelihood becuase copulas have identifiability problem, in the sense that two distributions can be different but still have same copula distribution.

To avoid this identifiability hassle, say, we fix one of the $\mu_1= 0$.

Now, I was wondering what would happen if we maximized the Copula likelihood for the parameter estimates. Is there a chance we  get the same estimates as in the Gaussian likelihood?

My main motivation for this question is that the only difference between  maximizing the Gaussian likelihood and Copula likelihood is the term $-\log({\prod_{j=1}^{2} ( 
\pi \Phi_{j}(X_{ij}; \mu_{1j} \Sigma_{1jj}) + (1-\pi) \Phi_{j}(X_{ij}; \mu_{2j} \Sigma_{1jj}) )  })$. So, intutively we should get the same parameters whether we maximize the copula likelihood or gaussian likelihood we should obtain the same parameters ( assuming we fix the identifiability problem). So, this extra term does not play any role during the maximization of the copula likelihood?

Thank you.